# Is it feasible to use 1kb .png image as background-image (On Repeat)?

Tags: css, png, web-optimization

I have created one png image from http://bg.siteorigin.com/. The size of that image is 1kb which I am using as background-image on body tag.

I want to know --- If I use another image of 500kb(1,920px * 1,080px) it will take more time to load and 500kb data consumption also. So if I use this .png image(1kb) on repeat how much data it will consume.

```
body {
   background-image:url("../path/imgName.png") ;
}
```

Does it make any difference for the same display size(1,920px * 1,080px)???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1 kilobyte image will consume 1 kilobyte of data. Browsers generally only load resources *once* no matter how many times you use them on the same page.

Example in practice:

[image: Example image] [image: Example image] [image: Example image] [image: Example image]

Despite being shown four times on this page, if you'll look in the network tab of your browser's developer tools you will see that it only loaded once.

Comment: So that means it will only load 1kb of data from server for that image, so it will not affect the website loading time.

Comment: It will affect the loading time (albeit minimally) for only _one_ image. When the image gets re-used the browser will grab its existing copy from its cache.